# Parsing text file lines

Tags: ruby, scripting, awk

I have a log file that contains, among other data, lines like these:

```
2012-05-23T20:52:11+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.com/practitioner_activities/10471/edit dyno=web.2 queue=0 wait=0ms service=866ms status=200 bytes=48799
2012-05-23T20:52:46+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.com/users/sign_out dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=20ms status=302 bytes=88
2012-05-23T20:52:46+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.com/ dyno=web.13 queue=0 wait=0ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=4680
2012-05-23T20:53:04+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.com/p/ENaCXExu7qNEqzwYYyPs dyno=web.5 queue=0 wait=0ms service=207ms status=302 bytes=119
2012-05-23T20:53:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.com/practitioner_activities/welcome dyno=web.3 queue=0 wait=0ms service=57ms status=200 bytes=5061
2012-05-23T20:53:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.com/assets/application-print-715276cc0b76d0d82db3ab5866f22a23.css dyno=web.14 queue=0 wait=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=76386
```

I'd like to parse them and dump them into a file I can open with excel for analysis. I need the Hour, Minute, Verb (GET or POST), url and the 'service=' time.

For example, for the first line above:

```
2012-05-23T20:52:11+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.com/practitioner_activities/10471/edit dyno=web.2 queue=0 wait=0ms service=866ms status=200 bytes=48799
```

I'd expect the output to look something like:

```
"20", "52", "GET", "myapp.com/practitioner_activities/10471/edit", "866"
```

How would I do this in `awk` or with a short ruby script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`, you could try something like:

```
awk '{ OFS="\", \""; split ($8, array, "="); printf "\"" substr ($1 , length ($1) - 13, 2 ) OFS substr ($1 , length ($1) - 10, 2 ) OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS substr (array[2], 0, length (array[2]) -2) "\"\n" }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
"20", "52", "GET", "myapp.com/practitioner_activities/10471/edit", "866"
"20", "52", "GET", "myapp.com/users/sign_out", "20"
"20", "52", "GET", "myapp.com/", "18"
"20", "53", "POST", "myapp.com/p/ENaCXExu7qNEqzwYYyPs", "207"
"20", "53", "GET", "myapp.com/practitioner_activities/welcome", "57"
"20", "53", "GET", "myapp.com/assets/application-print-715276cc0b76d0d82db3ab5866f22a23.css", "9"
```

HTH

**Edit:**

```
awk '{ OFS="\", \""; ORS="\"\n"; split ($8, array, "="); print "\"" substr ($1 , 12, 2 ), substr ($1 , 15, 2 ), $3, $4, array[2] + 0 }' file.txt
```

Thanks Dennis! The code is much much nice now :-)

Comment: You could use `ORS = "\"\n"` and `print` with commas (instead of explicitly saying `OFS` repeatedly, however you'd still set `OFS` as you have) instead of `printf` (since you're not using a format string). Or you could `printf "\"%d" OFS "%d" OFS "%s" OFS "%s" OFS "%d\"\n", substr($1, length($1) - 13, 2), substr($1, length($1) - 10, 2), $3, $4, substr(array[2], 0, length(array[2]) - 2)` which separates presentation and data. Also, in this last case, you could use a shorter variable name than `OFS`. Using `length` isn't really necessary. The timestamp is fixed length (you're relying on ...

Comment: ... that already. Just use an offset from the left instead of the right. The hour would be `substr($1, 12, 2)`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Points noted. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to tell you about a trick you can use to convert a number with trailing letters such as "866ms": `array[2] + 0` (instead of `substr (array[2], 0, length (array[2]) - 2)`). It coerces the string into a number dropping trailing (only) non-digits.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Wow cute trick! This must be like the 10th thing you've taught me today!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A ruby answer

```
ruby -ane '
    hr, min = $F[0][/(?<=T)\d\d:\d\d/].split(/:/)
    svc = $F[7].split(/=/)[-1]; svc[/ms/] = ""
    puts %q{"%d", "%d", "%s", "%s", "%d"} % [hr, min, $F[2], $F[3], svc]
' logfile
```